# Looking for cheap international bank to bank transfer in USD

Tags: international, money-transfer

I would like to transfer money from US bank account to a foreign (Poland) USD bank account. So no currency exchange involved. It seems that most services assume the currency exchange. The sites of the money transfer companies usually do not provide specific information until one creates an account.

Therefore, does anyone of you know of a cheap way to make such a transfer?

Comment: While they may be, I find plenty of such in parallel threads.

Answer (score 1):

What does cheap mean? *Compared to what*?

A standard international wire transfer cost about 40 $. Is that 'cheap' for you?

Alternatively, a mailed paper check takes 5-7 days mailing plus 7-10 days processing, but is free, that's as cheap as it gets.

Comment: Cheap meaning cheaper than the "standard" US international wire transfer. Xoom or RiaTransfer do this for 5 $ and that is OK, but the change of currency is required.

Mail post is cheap, but I need to get money to a bank account.

Comment: `about 40 $. Is that 'cheap' for you?` of course 40$ is NOT cheap for anybody, unless the person sends $ 10K-20K+